# condition of a start time display some link and if ends time to hide the link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

model code

```
def current
result = where("starts_at <= :now and ends_at >= :now", now: Time.zone.now)
result = result.where("id not log_in_now (?)", hidden_ids) if hidden_ids.present?
result
```

view

```
 <% unless @unit.current %>
       <% unless ContestantVote.friendship_exists?(current_user, @unit )%>
          <%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i>&nbspVote '.html_safe, vote_url(:unit_id => @unit.id,:user_id => current_user.id, :contestant_id => contestant.id), :class=>"cg ts fx",:style => " text-decoration:none;position: relative;left: 84px",:rel=>"external" %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

How to condition to display but its not working.

Comment: Could you elaborate more your question, I couldn't understand what are you trying to achieve here

Comment: ok i have a table call post and in the  post table contend start time and end        if it git to the end time stop displaying the link of that post